# Unable to Override OnCreate of an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, overriding, oncreate

I have 2 Activities, one which is MainActivity and the other, ReadActivity.

Whenever I started ReadActivity from MainActivity, the Activity started but it shows nothing, just the android:label value in the Manifest file.

As I was investigating, I tried putting a Log in ReadActivity but I noticed that the OnCreate method isn't called as I forgot to override the method but when I put the "@Override" above the OnCreate method I get the followong error:

"The method OnCreate(Bundle) of type ReadActivity must override or implement a supertype method".

I don't get what's wrong with this line, I've crossed checked it so many times, compared the codes with other application's code but I just can't seem to override it. Can anyone help me? Below are the codes of my project.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.rangga.elearning.ngaji;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView txtLogo, txtVersion;
    Button btnRead, btnIndex, btnAbout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Typeface font =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "assets/Schoolbell.ttf");

        txtLogo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLogo);
        txtVersion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVersion);
        btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
        btnIndex = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIndex);
        btnAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);

        /* txtLogo.setTypeface(font);
        txtVersion.setTypeface(font);
        btnRead.setTypeface(font);
        btnIndex.setTypeface(font);
        btnAbout.setTypeface(font); */

        btnRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                callIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    public void callIntent(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ReadActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**ReadActivity**

```
package com.rangga.elearning.ngaji;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ReadActivity extends Activity{

    private static String TAG = "ReadActivity";

    @Override
    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){        

        Log.i(TAG, "ReadActivity dimulai");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.read);          
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rangga.elearning.ngaji"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
              android:targetSdkVersion="7"
              android:maxSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".ReadActivity"
            android:label="Baca"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you.

Comment: O should be in small of onCreate see your MainActivity.................................

Comment: OMG, LOL. I can't believe I spent 3 hours just for that, thanks a lot man!

Comment: happens some time when you are looking for a big issue and skip things like this..

Comment: Yeah, it's been ages since I stat programming again. LOL, this is kinda embarassing. Thanks again man, you rock! :D

Answer (score 1):

`onCreate()` not `OnCreate()` . Besides, your manifest doesn't contain `Intent` information for your `ReadActivity`.

Comment: Should Intent always be contained in the manifest? Isn't it only for like the main Activity? Sorry, total newb. Thanks.

Comment: No need for an IntentFilter in the manifest if you start an activity like this: Intent i = new Intent(this, ReadActivity.class);

Comment: It is a good practice to include information about your `Activity` in the `Intent Filter`. It conveys stuff about your `Activity` like if it's a `launcher`, or `default` , etc.

Comment: I don't really know what's the difference between launcher, default, etc.. but I'll definitely look more into it as I go along. Thanks again hey. Arigatou gozaimasu Kazekage-sama :D